# Vue transition works on router-view but not inside component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

When I setup a typical route transition everything works as expected

```
<transition name="view" mode="out-in">
  <router-view />
</transition>
```

But if I try to put the transition inside a view instead, the transition doesn't work

```
<template>
  <transition name="view" mode="out-in">
    <main>
      <...>
    </main>
  </transition>
</template>
```

Any ideas why this could be the case?

Comment: Do you have something to transition inside the `main`?

Comment: @SándorBakos Yes. Sorry if it wasn't clear. I just didn't want to include the entire template in the post for brevity

Comment: is the `<router-view>` inside `main`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue, seems to me, is that the `<main>` element is not entering or leaving, so it doesn't animate. You're probably trying to animate something within the `<main>` element which does not get targeted by the `<transition>` pseudo-element.

my suggestion is to encapsulate the element that's being toggled (`v-if`) or having visibility toggled (`v-show`) with `transition`

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <transition name="view" mode="out-in">
      <...something with a v-if or a v-show>
    </transition>
  </main>
</template>
```

Also, if you have are using a list/array (`v-for`) you should use `transition-group`

docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html